# How can I rotate an antenna pattern in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, wireless

I have the data of an antenna pattern (azimuth, elevation, gain: including 361x361 numbers). I wanted to rotate the elevation by function `circshift()`. However, when I rotated the elevation angle and checked the antenna pattern by using function `patternCustom(Mag, Theta, Phi)`, the back lobe of the antenna disappeared. How can I fix it?

I may be not familiar with the definition of `patternCustom()`.

Here is my function to rotate the elevation angle:

```matlab
function shifted = shiftEl(mag, rot)
    shifted = zeros(size(mag));
    for i = 0 : 360
        shifted(1 + i * 361 : 361 + i * 361) = circshift(mag(1 + i * 361 : 361 + i * 361), rot);
    end
end
```

In the main function, I rotated elevation angle (90-Phi) by rotating magnitude:

```matlab
mag_shift = shiftEl(mag, 30);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your provided code, it seems that you are trying to rotate the elevation angles of an antenna pattern by using the 'circshift' function in MATLAB. However, this approach is not appropriate for rotating the elevation angles.

The 'circshift' function is designed for circular shifting of elements within an array, which means it shifts the values without altering their order or relationship. In the case of antenna patterns, simply shifting the magnitude values without adjusting the corresponding elevation angles will not result in a proper rotation of the pattern.

To correctly rotate the elevation angles, you need to modify the elevation data directly rather than shifting the magnitude values. Here's an example of how you can rotate the elevation angles:

Define the rotation angle in degrees

```
rotation_angle = 30
```

Convert rotation angle to radians

```
rotation_angle_rad = deg2rad(rotation_angle)
```

Rotate elevation angles

```
rotated_elevation = Theta + rotation_angle_rad
```

Ensure that rotated_elevation is within the valid range (0 to pi)

```
rotated_elevation = mod(rotated_elevation, pi)
```

Visualize the rotated antenna pattern using patternCustom or other visualization methods

```
patternCustom(mag, rotated_elevation, Phi)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 

Your answer appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). A heads-up that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

We do hope you'll continue to be a part of our community and contribute with *your own*, quality posts in the future. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, the parameter I gave patternCustom() is Phi (Azimuth) from 180 to 180, Theta(90-Elevation) from -180 to 180 and relevant antenna gain values. All 361^2 values are based on degree. It seems your code still not work...